# Submit a specific dynamically generated form amongst other forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a page that generates a number of forms - in HTML when parsed looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
    <input name="varenummer" type="hidden" value="1234"> 
    <input class="form-control-inline" name="antal" size="1" type="text" value="5"><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm myFavoriteClass" id="updateantal-1234" type="button">Opdater</button>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="form">
    <input name="varenummer" type="hidden" value="5678"> 
    <input class="form-control-inline" name="antal" size="1" type="text" value="13"><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm myFavoriteClass" id="updateantal-5678" type="button">Opdater</button>
</form>
```

What I want is for the javascript only to submit the form from where the button is pressed.

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".myFavoriteClass", function() {
        function a() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/pages/s_updateantal.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                async: !0,
                cache: !1,
                data: t,
                success: function(a) {
                    $("#result").html(a), $("#updateantal").attr("disabled", !1)
                }
            })
        }
        var t = $("form").serialize();
        $(".bs-example-modal-sm").modal("show"),
            $("#updateantal").attr("disabled", !0), 
            setTimeout(a, 1e3)
    })
});
```

Unfortunately I am no pro in javascript - When the `/pages/s_updateantal.php` file is parsed I can see that no matter which button I press it is the last form that is submitted. I have tried to name the buttons with an unique id, but it still just "submits" the last form.

Is there a way where you in the OnClick function can point to the form only where the button within has been pressed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to grab the parent form. Not var t = $("form").serialize(); but var t = $(this).parent().serialize();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to find the form that contains the button that raised the event using `closest()`. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".myFavoriteClass", function() {
    function a() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/pages/s_updateantal.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            async: !0,
            cache: !1,
            data: t,
            success: function(a) {
                $("#result").html(a), $("#updateantal").attr("disabled", !1)
            }
        })
    }
    var t = $(this).c.losest('form').serialize(); // <- closest() here
    $(".bs-example-modal-sm").modal("show"); 
    $("#updateantal").attr("disabled", !0);
    setTimeout(a, 1e3)
})
```

Your use of `!0` and `!1` is a little odd - it's better practice to use the `true` and `false` keywords.

Comment: I see - That makes sense and it works just fine now. I know that the !0 and !1 are odd - It was an old javascript file I had, that I "deminified", but you're right. Thanks a lot @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Also note that using the submit event would be wiser here. A form could also be submitted by hitting the enter key for example, and your js won't catch that now, while the submi event would catch all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use JavaScript for tasks that the browser can handle better than you!

If you use a `<button type="submit">` inside each form, it will submit exactly the form it belongs to.

Now, if you want to send the forms using AJAX, don't listen to a click-event, but to the form submit-event:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var theSubmittedForm = $(event.target);

    /* your AJAX code here */
})
```